# Transcrição fonológica/fonética

Tags: fonologia, fonética

Estou em dúvida sobre a transcrição fonética e fonológica de uma palavra; talvez essa dúvida surgiu devido ao fato de eu não ter compreendido muito bem a diferença entre fonética e fonologia.

Ao meu entender, a fonética estuda os sons produzidos pelo humano de forma fisiológica, ou seja, estuda o processo de formação biológica do som. Enquanto a fonologia estuda o som no contexto linguístico, ou seja, como ele pode ser usado em um contexto de comunicação.

Pelo menos foi isso que consegui compreender. Para mim, as pesquisas que realizei não foram claras o suficiente para fazer uma distinção entre ambos os termos.

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre a transcrição fonológica e fonética de uma palavra, o que eu sei é que a transcrição fonológica é realizada com barras, enquanto que a fonética com colchetes. Mas, não faço a mínima ideia do que seria uma transcrição fonológica. O que a transcrição fonológica representa exatamente?

Eu apenas consegui entender a transcrição fonética, que é simplesmente a representação gráfica dos sons utilizando o IPA ou API em PT, ex:

Legal [lɛgau]

Vendo essa definição de fonologia: "A fonologia estuda a maneira como os sons se organizam em uma linguagem, como a estrutura silábica, os acentos e entonações." [Fonte](https://www.diferenca.com/fonetica-e-fonologia/#:%7E:text=Qual%20a%20diferen%C3%A7a%20entre%20fon%C3%A9tica,de%20som%20em%20linguagens%20espec%C3%ADficas.&text=A%20fon%C3%A9tica%20%C3%A9%20o%20estudo,percep%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20e%20sons%20da%20fala.) eu pude entender que uma transcrição fonológica seria uma transcrição que inclui todas as possibilidades de entonação, pausa e tonacidade de uma palavra, enquanto que uma transcrição fonética seria apenas uma representação gráfica sem esses detalhes adicionais.

Meu raciocínio está correto, alguém poderia me tirar essa dúvida?

Comment: Correção: legal [lɛgaw] ou [legaw].

Comment: Não vou responder, pois, não estou apto a isso, mas vou tentar. Fonologicamente os Ts em "ta-te-ti-to-tu" são iguais, então "djisse" = "disse" são iguais; foneticamente, são diferentes. Geralmente, transcrições fonológicas usam a própria escrita da palavra — ex.: "desde" —, porque "desde" pode ser pronunciado como "dêsde", "dêisde", "dêsdji", "dêisdji", "dêsdi" ou "dêisdi", podendo haver muitas outras maneiras.

Comment: A diferença entre "//" e "[]" não é essa. Pelo que sei, não há regra oficial, mas "//" é geralmente usado para 1 fonema, 1 ditongo, 1 tritongo, 1 hiato ou 1 encontro consonantal. "[]" é mais usado para palavras inteiras ou mais especificação, mas nenhum impede ao outro.

Comment: Acho, mas não me leves a sério: pode se dizer que a fonologia se importa com o valor gramatical duma palavra, pois, muitas vezes, "paço" ≠ "passo", enquanto, na fonética, "passo" = "paço". A fonética está interessado no valor fonético ou sonoro, então, podemos tratar de dialetos; o meu dialeto paulista fala "sal" como [sɑʊ̯] e "canto" como [kɐ̃ŋtʊ], porém, se eu falar "sal" como [saʊ̯] ou [saw], não diferença GRAMATICAL. P.S.: há quem distingua "paço" de "passo".

Comment: @Schilive Ok, entendi! Então, baseado nas suas afirmações, eu poderia afirmar o que disse anteriormente: uma transcrição fonológica seria uma transcrição que inclui todas as possibilidades de entonação, pausa e tonacidade de uma palavra, enquanto que uma transcrição fonética seria apenas uma representação gráfica sem esses detalhes adicionais.

Comment: Não existe "transcrição fonológica".  Uma transcrição é escritura que se escreve basado numa gravação ou nas pessoas falando (em um tribunal, p. ex.).

Answer (score 3):

Essa é um questão que sempre aflinge quem não é da área e quem começa a estudar fonética e/ou fonologia. A sua definição está correta:

• **Fonética** é o estudo dos sons de forma mais física, chegando até a questões mais acústicas, como quando se analisa um espectrograma. Portanto, é o estudo do som como ele é;

• **Fonologia** é o estudo de sons importantes para a língua, que são distintivos. Como por exemplo: vendo a palavra "bar" e "mar", sabemos que /b/ e /m/ são dois sons importantes e que distinguem significado na língua portuguesa.

Sabendo tudo isso, podemos falar de unidades mínimas: o fone e o fonema. Quando um som diferencia o significado de um par mínimo (como "bar" e "mar") dizemos que este som é um *fonema* (escrevemo-los com barras / /). Quando queremos descrever fora desta parte lingüística, mostrando como realmente se diz, usamos *fones* (escrevemo-los com colchetes [ ]).

A transição FONÊMICA, portanto FONOLÓGICA da palavra "tio" em vários dialetos brasileiros é /'tiu/, enquanto a palavra "tato" /'tatu/ é escrita com exatamente os mesmos fonemas /t/. Mas a sua realização, dado o contexto em que ocorre, é outra! E é aí que entram os fones e a transcrição FONÉTICA: /'tio/ é realizado como [ˈt͡ʃiʊ] e /'tatu/ é realizado como [ˈtatʊ]. Assim sabemos que [t͡ʃ] e [t] não distinguem significado, são fones que são realizações diferentes do mesmo fonema /t/ (chamamos fones do mesmo fonema de *alofones*).